# Small, light text editor / note taker with built-in strong encryption?

Tags: software-rec, encryption, text-editing

I've been using a little app called [SafeSex](http://download.cnet.com/SafeSex/3000-2092_4-10357746.html) to jot down notes securely; however it's not been maintained for ages and lacks polish. However, it does have Blowfish encryption built-in.

My question is: does anyone know of a reasonably polished alternative that supports encrypted note-taking? I'm aware of TrueCrypt, but I'd rather have a light app I could use securely on random machines without worrying about leaving copies my notes behind.

Comment: can the tag change from lotus-notes to just notes... since it's not about lotus-notes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LockNote](http://sourceforge.net/projects/locknote/) works for me.

> Store your most valuable notes in a LockNote. Hide your everyday notes in a safe place. Application and document in one: the mechanism to encrypt and decrypt a note is part of it. Secure, simple, independent. No installation required.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! LockNote appears to be small, polished and friendly. Although I'm not quite sure what to think of its behavior of converting text files to encrypted EXEs.

Comment: Why does it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

[NotepadCrypt](http://www.andromeda.com/people/ddyer/notepad/NotepadCrypt-technotes.html)

> "**Overall Design:** Sha256 hash is used to convert an ascii pass phrase to a 256 bit encryption key.  Pseudorandom data is used as an initialization vector for AES-256 encryption.  Optionally, a the encryption key (NOT the passphrase)  is encrypted using a second master key, and included in the file header.  This master key can be used as an emergency data recovery key, or as a second key to be used by programs to read encrypted files."
>
> [Continue Reading...](http://www.andromeda.com/people/ddyer/notepad/NotepadCrypt-technotes.html)

Comment: Son of a...beat me again.

Comment: SHA-256 isn't the best choice for generating encryption key from pass phrases. If it doesn't use salt than it's very far from strong encryption. There functions designed for this, like PBKDF2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2

Answer (score 1):

[KryptoPad](http://kryptopad.com/)

> "KryptoPad is a simple yet effective Notepad-like application with built-in text encryption and decryption functions. Its handy interface provides one-click encryption and decryption of entered or loaded text, as long as usual notepad-like operations. "

Answer (score 1):

[TextCrypt](http://software.enlightware.com/free/en/textcrypt/)

> TextCrypt is a small and easy to use application that will encrypt/decrypt your text messages quickly and easily. Texts can be de- and encrypted with just a few clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm Safesex comes with source code, so a friendly Stackoverflow user might be able to polish it up...

though Sophos anti-virus is not keen on it